# Install OpenCV on a C++ compiler

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, dev-c++

I am used with using OpenCV with python. But does someone have an idea how to add openCV library to a C++ compiler (such DevCpp or CodeBlocks...).

If there is a compiler on which it's easier to install OpenCV library no problem, I have no restriction conserning the compiler.

I followed some tutos on the net but they were not so clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Opencv is built with CMake which allows it to be easily compiled using a wide range of compilers and IDEs. If you use CMake with your application adding opencv is also very simple (3 or 4 lines of text in your CMakeLists.txt after building opencv from source). If you don't you have to make sure you use binaries built for your compiler ( and in the case of Visual Studio don't mix Debug and Release and make sure you do not use binaries from a different version of vc) and also you will have to manually add linker commands (or dependencies) to your project or makefile.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has two important phases of compilation. First, each individual .cpp file is needed. You need the library header files (.h) for this. Secondly, the separate parts are linked together, and you need the library files themselves. (.lib/.a depending on platform).

So, you need to provide paths to both. The compiler knows which exact headers are needed from the `#include` statement, but the libraries to link must be explicitly listed.

Comment: hahaha I didn't think of it at all even though it's the natural method of including libraries

Comment: Thank you MSalters,

The most important remark is to add OpenCV path to the c++ compiler options (Dev-Cpp). Otherwise it will not work.

In my case the path is : 

    "C:\opencv\build\include".

in this folder, there are "opencv" and "opencv2" folders. So I need to include "openCV.hpp" which is in "opencv2" folder.

Here a small test code:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    int main(){printf("working");}

Comment: Your test program below covers only the processus of linking the headers (confirms that the compiler knows where the .hpp files are). In order to make sure that OpenCV libraries had been linked correctly, please mind testing one of OpenCV functions like cvLoadImafe(). This is where things get messy for most of those trying to configure the linker for using OpenCV for the first time.